# Cpan on Vicidial not working after kernel update on Centos7

Tags: centos7, cpan

```
Jul 04 21:32:22 Installed: lame-libs-3.99.5-8.el7.x86_64
Jul 04 21:32:22 Updated: kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64
Jul 04 21:32:22 Updated: kernel-tools-3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64
Jul 04 21:32:22 Updated: lame-3.99.5-8.el7.x86_64
Jul 04 21:32:23 Updated: python-perf-3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64
Jul 04 21:32:30 Installed: kernel-3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64
Jul 04 21:32:31 Updated: kernel-headers-3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64
Jul 04 21:33:01 Installed: kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64
Jul 10 19:59:33 Updated: kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
Jul 10 19:59:33 Updated: 32:bind-license-9.9.4-50.el7_3.1.noarch
Jul 10 19:59:34 Updated: 32:bind-libs-lite-9.9.4-50.el7_3.1.x86_64
Jul 10 19:59:34 Updated: kernel-tools-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
Jul 10 19:59:34 Updated: python-perf-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
Jul 10 19:59:56 Installed: kernel-devel-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
Jul 10 20:00:03 Installed: kernel-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
Jul 10 20:00:04 Updated: kernel-headers-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
```

I have made a simple yum update and now when I try to upload a xls file for example, system shows "" instead of xls content.. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
sh: /var/www/html/application/views/go_list/sheet2tab.pl: Permission denied

it was a permission issue